# send using smtp both name and email through body of letter

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

good evening everone , i have phpmailer code which allow me to connect to smtp google service and send a message through it , here is the code

```
 <?php 
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
include("class.smtp.php"); 
$sname="=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($sname)."?=\n";
$smail=""; 
$rname="=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($rname)."?=\n"; 
$rmail="";
$sub="=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($sub)."?=\n"; 
$body=$n;   
$sname=$_POST['element_2'];
$n= $_POST['element_1'] . $_POST['element_3'];
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$gmail="account@gmail.com";
$gpass="password";
$mail->Username = $gmail; 
$mail->Password = $gpass; 
$mail->AddReplyTo($smail,$sname); 
$rmail = "receive@hotmail.com";
$rname="me";
$mail->AddAddress($rmail, $rname); 
$mail->From = $smail; 
$mail->FromName = $sname;
$mail->Subject = $sub; 
$mail->MsgHTML($body); 
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "fail";
}else{
echo "success";
}
?>
```

the problem is , i can't get the name of the sender 
i 've tried to insert it into body but it  couldn't success

```
$n= $_POST['element_1'] . $_POST['element_3'];
```

my 2nd issue is 
i have also a 3 radio buttons for the subject , i've used

```
if(isset($_POST['radio1'])){
$sub = "free";
}
if(isset($_POST['radio2'])){
$sub = "premium";
}
```

but still receive empty subject
could you please help me 
thanks in advance

---

thanks for your time , me first issue was solved ,
thanks to you , 
but the second one unfortunately didn't. i've  gave radio buttons the same name and change their value as following

```
<input id="element_4_1" name="element_4" class="element radio" type="radio" value="free" />
<input id="element_4_1" name="element_4" class="element radio" type="radio" value="premium" />
```

when i select a radio button it suppose to have the value free or premium but it have the value 1 
i tried your code (i've put it right under $n  value )

```
$sub = isset($_POST['element_4']) ? $_POST['element_4'] : "no subject";
```

and tried this

```
$sub = $_POST['element_4'];
```

but it didn't work 
could you goon with your help please 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put

```
$body=$n;
```

after

```
$n= $_POST['element_1'] . $_POST['element_3'];
```

it works if in fact `$_POST['element_1'] and $_POST['element_3']` are being posted to this page !

and as for your radio buttons 
all of them should have the same name and there values should be the subject of your email

```
$sub = isset($_POST['radio']) ? $_POST['radio'] : "no subject";
```